# In javascript, how can I create element which has many attributes with createElement() in one line?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
`<div class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="buy" value="260" checked="" onclick="javascript:basket.checkItem();">&nbsp;</div>
```

this is element that I want to make by createElement().
I want to know is there anyway complete this in one command? length doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a one-liner, you could use:

```js
Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {className: 'check', innerHTML: '<input type="checkbox" name="buy" value="260" checked="" onclick="javascript:basket.checkItem();">&nbsp;'})
```

Or, better readable:

```js
Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {
  className: 'check',
  innerHTML: '<input type="checkbox" name="buy" value="260" checked="" onclick="javascript:basket.checkItem();">&nbsp;'
})
```

Comment: Why use innerHTML, when you could instead append elements via DOM? You get linter/checker support that way.

Comment: @SamHughes Just because OP asked for a one-line solution.

Comment: I mean, the arbitrary one-line restriction is as crazy as it is unconstrained. Using an IIF approach, you've got it created, properties assigned, and then same for each child. for instance: `toldYouSo = (eMaker, head, ...fam) => {head = eMaker(head); fam.forEach(c=>head.appendElement(eMaker(c)); return head;})(tagData=>object.assign(document.createElement(tagData.tag, tagData), {tag: "div", className: "check"}, {tag: "input", type: "checkbox", name: "buy", value: "260", checked: "", onclick: "javascript:basked.checkItem();"})` ... Lordy, I miss JS. Typechecking is nice, but Golang is hell.